# java.io.IOException: org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException

Tags: java, jaxb, apache-camel, marshalling

I am new to Apache Camel and Blueprint DSL and I am trying to marshal a bean to xml using jaxb but getting the following exception:

> java.io.IOException: org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException: No type converter available to convert from type: com.test.rqst.InitiateReq to the required type: java.io.InputStream with value com.test.rqst.InitiateReq@681d07ed

My blueprint.xml is as follows

```
<bean id="testBean2" class="com.test.utility.StopTestDummy" />
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
<route id="timerToLog">
  <from uri="timer:foo?period=1000&amp;repeatCount=1"/>
  <bean id="testCastor" ref="testBean2"
              method="setDummyValues" />    
            <marshal>
                <jaxb prettyPrint="true" contextPath="com.scb.s2b.application.pymt.service.payment.stoppymt.rqst"/>
            </marshal>
   <log message="After Marshalling ${body}"/>      
  <to uri="mock:result"/>
</route>    
</camelContext>
```

The method `setDummyValues` inside `StopTestDummy` class is creating the `POJO(InitiateReq)` as I wanted and returing the same. But I keep getting the error. What am I doing wrong.

Many Thanks.

Comment: It may help (similar issue):
http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/NoTypeConversionAvailableException-td5766952.html

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is the issue, but check these out.

First, are you marhsalling the *correct* class?
Exception says `com.test.rqst.InitiateReq`, while in your code you tell JAXB to marshal a different package: `<jaxb contextPath="com.scb.s2b.application.pymt.service.payment.stoppymt.rqst"/>`

Second, did you tell JAXB about `InitiateReq` class?
Create a file named `jaxb.index` in the same package and insert the name of the classes you want to marshal/unmarshal (only a line with `InitiateReq` in your case)